# Salesforce Deployment techniques for one to many distributions of code

Tags: apex, deployment

I have developed a connector code to send updates from Salesforce using apex and REST based APIs to my external website. Now i have to deploy the changes.

How can i make this code available for all my clients, and for new upcoming clients. so it would be a one to many distribution.

**I don't want to use Packages**. Is there any other alternative approach available? if yes please specify the Pros and Cons and how it is better than the packages.

Comment: You would incur an enormous amount of technical debt maintaining a 1-to-many deployment solution that isn't packages, if you needed the same upgradeability. My colleague built a deployment tool that ties into github that's worth a look, although it was built for team dev and CI: http://developer.salesforcefoundation.org/mrbelvedere/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. After deploying with this tool how would i provide it to my clients for installation? So do you mean otherwise if i have to deploy without any cost i should use Packages only?  thanks,Mani

Comment: Can you elaborate on why packages aren't an option?

Comment: I mean that you will write and maintain a lot of code to effectively deploy to many orgs without packages. I would not recommend this to any ISV.